# Нужно ли здесь обособлять выражение "классе в пятом"?

Tags: запятые

> Мы с Олей классе в пятом ходили на кружок.

Одноклассница яростно доказывает, что данная часть обособляется, а все правила, наоборот, на моей стороне.

Comment: "Все правила" - о каких именно правилах идет речь?

Comment: Об обособлении второстепенных членов предложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу причин обособлять обстоятельство времени. Обособляются уточняющие, пояснительные и присоединительные члены предложения, но слова “классе в пятом” таковыми не являются.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ неоднозначный, в таких случаях возможны оба варианта, например:

У меня в памяти промелькнуло воспоминание, как мы, **классе в третьем**, впервые отправились в горы небольшой группкой.

**Классе в девятом** у меня были длинные волосы, не припомню, чтобы с ними были какие-то проблемы

**Классе в третьем** нам задали сочинение на тему «Моя мечта».

В свое время ― **должно быть, классе в седьмом** ― я упивалась «Сагой о Форсайтах».

Мы видим, что **обстоятельству можно придать уточняющее значение,** и это зависит от **структуры** предложения. **В начале предложения** оборот обычно не обособляется, а вот **в середине** он обособляется чаще (например, позиция между подлежащим и сказуемым удобна для обособления).

Примеры решения:

**(1) Мы с Олей, классе в пятом, ходили на кружок. (2) Классе в пятом мы с Олей  ходили на кружок.**

Comment: "Воспоминание, как мы, классе в третьем, впервые отправились в горы небольшой группкой."  => Здесь основное:  воспоминание, как мы впервые отправились в горы, а "классе в пятом" - второстепеная информация. Не хотите ли Вы сказать, что  "Мы с Олей ходили на кружок" - основная мысль, а то, что это было в школьные годы,  - второстепенная информация? Это по поводу примера (1).

Comment: А в примере (2) — акцент на том, что это было классе в пятом. Хотел ли автор так расставить акценты?

Comment: Да в этих примерах один принцип: детерминант в начале предложения стоит на своем месте и не обособляется, а если это обстоятельство поставили между подлежащим и сказуемым, то его удобно обособить. В русской пунктуации действует единая система: смысл управляет пунктуацией через структуру, а не напрямую. Хочу придать уточняющий характер - значит, меняю структуру, ставлю обстоятельство между подлежащим и сказуемым. А если оно там стоит и не обособляется, то предложение смотрится странно, как будто в нем слова перемешаны.и непонятно, что это обстоятельство там делает.

Comment: Здесь обстоятельство имеет важное значение: без него нельзя себе предствить, детьми они ходили туда или начинающими альпинистами, у которых на пенсии появилось такое хобби. Предложение с такой же структурой из классики: "... **ты** в молодые годы **умел** рассудку страсти подчинять".

Comment: 1) Стихи - это не проза, там  размер важен. 2) "В молодые годы" - это не (кажется) "в классе пятом",  значение неточное. 3) Не хотите обособлять и уточнять - ставьте обстоятельство в начало предложения. 4) В тексте все слова должны быть на своем месте. Зачем применять инверсию, какой в ней смысл?. 5) Это  разговорная речь,  для нее характерна спонтанность, импровизация, отклонения от основного текста, попутные УТОЧНЕНИЯ и т.д. Впрочем на своем мнении, как всегда отличном от общего, не настаиваю.

Comment: Jasmin, мне кажется, что правильно говорить _ходить **в** кружок._

Comment: У Грамоты: Вопрос № 275526  
Как правильно сказать: она ходит в кружок танцев или на кружок танцев?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Нормативно: она занимается в кружке танцев, ходит на занятия танцевального кружка. В разговорной речи: ходит в кружок танцев и на кружок (=на занятия кружка).

Comment: Jasmin, я исходил из того, что в вопросе именно стихотворные строки: "Мы с Олей классе в пятом// ходили на кружок." В таком случае Вы согласны с отсутствием запятой? В прозе я бы выразился более пространно:  "В школьные годы, классе в пятом, мы с Олей ходили на кружок."

Comment: Обособление на чтение стихотворной строки не влияет, так как вводные слова далеко не всегда выделяются интонационно. Если они попадают в сложное предложение,  то подчиняются его интонации, а если присутствуют в  стихотворении, то вписываются в его ритм.